# Custom post type `if( array_key_exists` else query

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, if-statement

I have configured a `custom_post_type` to display multiple pages using

```
function discovr_campaign_endpoints() {
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'overview', EP_PERMALINK );
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'new-campaign-details', EP_PERMALINK );
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'new-campaign-audience', EP_PERMALINK );
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'new-campaign-page', EP_PERMALINK );
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'new-campaign-ads', EP_PERMALINK );
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'edit-campaign', EP_PERMALINK );
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'analytics', EP_PERMALINK );
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'preview-campaign', EP_PERMALINK );
}

add_action( 'init', 'discovr_campaign_endpoints' );
```

and within the `single-post-type.php`

```
<?php 
if( array_key_exists( 'overview', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-overview.php");
} 
if( array_key_exists( 'new-campaign-details', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-new-details.php");
}
if( array_key_exists( 'new-campaign-audience', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-new-audience.php");
} 
if( array_key_exists( 'new-campaign-page', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-new-page.php");
} 
if( array_key_exists( 'new-campaign-ads', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-new-ads.php");
} 
if( array_key_exists( 'edit-campaign', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-edit.php");
} 
if( array_key_exists( 'analytics', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-analytics.php");
}
if( array_key_exists( 'preview-campaign', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-preview.php");
}?>
```

to display the appropriate content for each page as per each `endpoint`

However, I would still like to display

```
<?php the_content();?>
```

if these pages are not being shown, in the `single-post-type.php` page.

I have tried using

```
if( array_key_exists( 'new-campaign-details', $wp_query->query_vars ) )
{
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-new-details.php");
}else{
     echo the_content();
}
```

on each, however, this then will display `the_content` multiple times and I believe I need a way to add an `if(*first* array_key_exists)` statement around individual `elseif( array_key_exists` to query whether any of these endpoints exist `else} echo the_content();`

like the below example (this seems to work and will if I replace accept `echo 'Hello World';` but not `the_content();`)

```
<?php 
if( array_key_exists( 'overview', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-overview.php");
} 
elseif( array_key_exists( 'new-campaign-details', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-new-details.php");
}
elseif( array_key_exists( 'new-campaign-audience', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-new-audience.php");
} 
elseif( array_key_exists( 'new-campaign-page', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-new-page.php");
} 
elseif( array_key_exists( 'new-campaign-ads', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-new-ads.php");
} 
elseif( array_key_exists( 'edit-campaign', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-edit.php");
} 
elseif( array_key_exists( 'analytics', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-analytics.php");
}
elseif( array_key_exists( 'preview-campaign', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-preview.php");
}
else{
    echo the_content();
}
?>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to worry, my solution was right, just missing some key points.

If anyone else is having this issue, doubt it. Silly mistake from an all-nighter.

It was

```
<?php 
if( array_key_exists( 'overview', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){

include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-overview.php");
} 
elseif( array_key_exists( 'new-campaign-details', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-new-details.php");
}
elseif( array_key_exists( 'new-campaign-audience', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-new-audience.php");
} 
elseif( array_key_exists( 'new-campaign-page', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-new-page.php");
} 
elseif( array_key_exists( 'new-campaign-ads', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-new-ads.php");
} 
elseif( array_key_exists( 'edit-campaign', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-edit.php");
} 
elseif( array_key_exists( 'analytics', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-analytics.php");
}
elseif( array_key_exists( 'preview-campaign', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-preview.php");
}
else{
    get_header('new');
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_content();
    endwhile;
    endif; 
    get_footer('new');
}
?>
```